# How to create post automatic after clicking chechout page in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

whenever someone purchases the product test, a new post is created and saved under the category with the post meta being set with key "order_id" being set to the order_id of the order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'test3' ); 
    function test3(){ 
        global $woocommerce; 
        print_r($woocommerce); 
        $my_post = array( 
            'post_title' => 'Test', 
            'post_content' => 'This is test post', 
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'post_author' => 1, 
            'post_category' => array( 8,39 ) 
          ); 

            // Insert the post into the database
            wp_insert_post( $my_post ); 
}
```

Comment: please add some code, have you tried anything?

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'test3' );
function test3(){

 global $woocommerce;
 print_r($woocommerce);
 
 
 $my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Test',
  'post_content'  => 'This is test post',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
);
 
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}



this  is the code

Comment: Please update your question with your attempted code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a new post with postmeta 'order_id' => 45 after checkout completion? if its so, my code will help you.

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'order_check', 10, 1);

function order_check($order_id) {

    $my_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'Test',
        'post_content' => 'This is test post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_category' => array(8, 39)
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'order_id', $order_id);
}
```

Comment: Please tell me about that how can i get cart quantity for doing a same thing?

Please resolve it as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: @adelinahenry , what you mean by cart quantity? total products?

Comment: Its okay i have got my answer my self Thanks..

i am Talking about it.

foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
$qty = $item['qty'];